# How does '..' works in directory address?

Tags: macos, ls

I interpret `..` as previous directory so I expect `/` == `/home/..`. I tried:

1. `ls -a /`
2. `ls -a /home/..`

and was expecting same result. But the result was different a little.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: result image]

The result of `ls -a /home/..`:

> - .
> - ..
> - .DS_Store
> - .DocumentRevisions-V100
> - .OSInstallerMessages
> - .Spotlight-V100
> - .TempReceipt.bom
> - .TemporaryItems
> - .file
> - .fseventsd
> - .installer-compatibility
> - .vol
> - Applications
> - Library
> - System
> - Users
> - Volumes
> - cores
> - home
> - mnt
> - opt
> - private
> - usr

The result of `ls -a /`:

> - .
> - ..
> - .file
> - .fseventsd
> - .DS_Store
> - .Volumeicon.icns
> - .vol
> - Applications
> - Volumes
> - etc
> - sbin
> - Library
> - bin
> - home
> - tmp
> - System
> - cores
> - opt
> - usr
> - Users
> - dev
> - private
> - var

Comment: What difference you see? They ought to be same

Comment: Sorry. I have just added result image

Comment: Can not see the image yet

Comment: @hoeeeeeh see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal

Comment: *`.DS_Store`* - You are using OS X, not Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/home` is a symlink. On a 10.15 system, it's a symlink to `/System/Volumes/Data/home`, so `/home/..` is `/System/Volumes/Data`.